# PHP message and PHP warning ZipArchive::close(): Write error: No space left on device

Tags: php, wordpress, diskspace

My environment code stack is a WordPress framework and recently I'm getting the error like "PHP message and PHP warning ZipArchive::close(): Write error: No space left on device" in error log but when I check disk space of my server there is lot of space is available and inode space is also available. Can anyone please help how to resolve this.

[my server disk space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5M2U.png)

Comment: can you share your result of space check on device?

Comment: added pls check and let me know